# can't compile QtPdfium using Mingw32 QT 5.12 to read PDF

Tags: c++, qt, pdfium

I want to extract text from PDF so I tried QPdfium From [here](https://github.com/paulovap/qtpdfium)
I tried to compile the library using QT 5.12.0 with Mingw32 compiler I followed this steps:
**1 -** I git a clone from the project and then open the qtpdfium.pro, select release mode with Mingw 32 compiler.
**2 -** when i start to build I got around 18 Error

```
D:\build\qtpdfium-master\src\3rdparty\pdfium\fpdfsdk\fsdk_actionhandler.cpp:425: error: 'class CPDF_Dest' has no member named 'GetObjectW'; did you mean 'GetObject'?
   const CPDF_Array* pMyArray = ToArray(MyDest.GetObject());
                                               ^
D:\build\qtpdfium-master\src\3rdparty\pdfium\fpdfsdk\fpdfview.cpp:447: error: 'g_pdfium_print_postscript_level' was not declared in this scope
   g_pdfium_print_postscript_level = postscript_level;
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:\build\qtpdfium-master\src\3rdparty\pdfium\fpdfsdk\fsdk_actionhandler.cpp:425: error: 'class CPDF_Dest' has no member named 'GetObjectW'; did you mean 'GetObject'?
   const CPDF_Array* pMyArray = ToArray(MyDest.GetObject());
                                               ^
D:\build\qtpdfium-master\src\3rdparty\pdfium\fpdfsdk\fpdfview.cpp:681: error: no matching function for call to 'MakeUnique<<expression error> >(HDC__*&)'
     pContext->m_pDevice = pdfium::MakeUnique<CFX_WindowsDevice>(dc);
                                                                   ^
D:\build\qtpdfium-master\src\3rdparty\pdfium\fpdfsdk\fpdfview.cpp:681: error: template argument 1 is invalid
     pContext->m_pDevice = pdfium::MakeUnique<CFX_WindowsDevice>(dc);
                                                                   ^
D:\build\qtpdfium-master\src\3rdparty\pdfium\fpdfsdk\fpdfview.cpp:681: error: template argument 1 is invalid
     pContext->m_pDevice = pdfium::MakeUnique<CFX_WindowsDevice>(dc);
                                                                   ^
D:\build\qtpdfium-master\src\3rdparty\pdfium\fpdfsdk\fpdfview.cpp:681: error: template argument 1 is invalid
     pContext->m_pDevice = pdfium::MakeUnique<CFX_WindowsDevice>(dc);
                                                                   ^
D:\build\qtpdfium-master\src\3rdparty\pdfium\fpdfsdk\fpdfview.cpp:688: error: 'CFX_WindowsDevice' was not declared in this scope
     CFX_WindowsDevice WinDC(dc);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:\build\qtpdfium-master\src\3rdparty\pdfium\fpdfsdk\fpdfview.cpp:689: error: 'WinDC' was not declared in this scope
     if (WinDC.GetDeviceCaps(FXDC_DEVICE_CLASS) == FXDC_PRINTER) {
         ^~~~~
D:\build\qtpdfium-master\src\3rdparty\pdfium\fpdfsdk\fpdfview.cpp:447: error: 'g_pdfium_print_postscript_level' was not declared in this scope
   g_pdfium_print_postscript_level = postscript_level;
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:\build\qtpdfium-master\src\3rdparty\pdfium\fpdfsdk\fpdfview.cpp:681: error: 'CFX_WindowsDevice' was not declared in this scope
     pContext->m_pDevice = pdfium::MakeUnique<CFX_WindowsDevice>(dc);
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:\build\qtpdfium-master\src\3rdparty\pdfium\fpdfsdk\fpdfview.cpp:681: error: no matching function for call to 'MakeUnique<<expression error> >(HDC__*&)'
     pContext->m_pDevice = pdfium::MakeUnique<CFX_WindowsDevice>(dc);
                                                                   ^
D:\build\qtpdfium-master\src\3rdparty\pdfium\fpdfsdk\fpdfview.cpp:681: error: template argument 1 is invalid
     pContext->m_pDevice = pdfium::MakeUnique<CFX_WindowsDevice>(dc);
                                                                   ^
D:\build\qtpdfium-master\src\3rdparty\pdfium\fpdfsdk\fpdfview.cpp:681: error: template argument 1 is invalid
     pContext->m_pDevice = pdfium::MakeUnique<CFX_WindowsDevice>(dc);
                                                                   ^
D:\build\qtpdfium-master\src\3rdparty\pdfium\fpdfsdk\fpdfview.cpp:681: error: template argument 1 is invalid
     pContext->m_pDevice = pdfium::MakeUnique<CFX_WindowsDevice>(dc);
                                                                   ^
D:\build\qtpdfium-master\src\3rdparty\pdfium\fpdfsdk\fpdfview.cpp:688: error: 'CFX_WindowsDevice' was not declared in this scope
     CFX_WindowsDevice WinDC(dc);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:\build\qtpdfium-master\src\3rdparty\pdfium\fpdfsdk\fpdfview.cpp:689: error: 'WinDC' was not declared in this scope
     if (WinDC.GetDeviceCaps(FXDC_DEVICE_CLASS) == FXDC_PRINTER) {
         ^~~~~
```

so what is the problem, in the readme file It say that I can compile it with no problem, I tried to compile using MSVC 2017 32 and it give me more errors 187 errors, so please any help if some one compiled it before, or if there any link to download the library in a binary instead of compiling it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of python are you using to compile your project?

Comment: I have python 2.7 in the system env but I compile using QT creator not cmd